# How to perform case in an oracle concat function?

Tags: oracle, select, case, concatenation

How to perform case in an oracle  concat  function ?
I want to concat number and a letter based on the number. ie if number is more     than 1 than i  have to append s else not.
I tried below query but its not working.

```
  Select concat(count(*) , if count(*) > 1 then 's' else '') 
  from tablename 
  group by columnname;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle it is better to use `||` for concatenation, and there's no `if` but there are `case` expressions. I will show the solution with `||` as it is best practice, but if you must use `concat` you can do it as well. Also, Oracle will convert a number to a VARCHAR2 for you, but it is best to write your conversions explicitly.

```
select to_char(count(*)) || case when count(*)  > 1 then 's' end from ....
```

NOTE - the default value of `case` is `''` (same as `NULL` in Oracle), so I didn't need to write more.

Comment: select to_char(count(*)) || case if count(*) > 1 then 'aa' end from occupations group by occupation 
* 
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Are you able to copy and paste? (Since simply copying a line of text seems to be too difficult.) I just told you that there is no `if` in Oracle. You wrote `if` where I wrote `when`. Do you see it now? If not, just copy and paste so there's no mis-transcribing.